# Highlight search result with Angular filter and hide non matching text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this example for highlighting a search result using Angular filter, the thing is that when you search for example 'suit' it highlight the word suit but all the non-matching text is still there.

http://demo.codeforgeek.com/highlight-angular/

How I can hide all text except the highlighted text and two or three word before and after this one?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the *<style>* part with below code:

```
<style>
  .highlighted { color:#000; background: yellow }
  div.container ul div { color:#fff }
</style>
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: This leaves an empty space and I need to show some word before and after the highlight. I also can't do display none and then display the highlighted text.

Comment: Please  describe your problem better. I dont understand what you want sorry.

Comment: and downvoting an only answer without trying to improve or ask for addition, is not a good idea..

Comment: oh! I didn't downvoted anything, many thanks for your answer. Well what I exactly need is what your solution does but also I have to remove the empty space that a white color leaves.